# Is something eating up my home partition?

Tags: disk-usage

Since I've updated to 11.10, my home partition keeps filling itself up to full, but I have no idea what it is that is doing it.  I've managed to remove about 28gb (35gb capacity on the partition) but it keeps getting full without me even doing anything!

This is causing me issues as I cannot listen to any music, or even log back into my system if I log out again.  I get no warnings from Ubuntu that the partition is getting full, so my system suddenly becomes sluggish.

The Disk Usage Analyser doesn't give anyway anything suspicious that's sticking out to me that's climbing in disk usage.

**Edit**: After running the command

```
du -sch $HOME/.[a-z]*
```

I've just noticed a rather large file...

```
26G /home/tom/.xsession-errors
```

Surely this shouldn't be that large!

**Edit 2**: I did

```
cat .xsession-errors | less
```

on the file, and it's filled with lines like this:

```
11:15:10.436 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
11:15:10.436 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
11:15:10.436 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
11:15:10.436 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
11:15:10.436 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
11:15:10.436 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
11:15:10.436 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
11:15:10.436 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
11:15:10.437 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
11:15:10.437 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
11:15:10.437 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
11:15:10.437 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
11:15:10.437 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
11:15:10.437 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
11:15:10.437 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
11:15:10.437 I [fsevents:287] got event 2 with cookie 0 on 1748: /home/tom//.xsession-errors
```

**Edit 3**: Issue seems to be with the Spotify native client writing to the .xsession-errors file.  I've reported the bug here: http://getsatisfaction.com/spotify/topics/spotify_is_writing_an_obscene_amount_of_information_to_error_file

Comment: what does DUL give, because AFAIK it shows which folder/file uses what amount of disk! Any screenshot?

Comment: Can you post the output of running the command `du -sch $HOME/.[a-z]*` from a terminal?  That should give a hint of what is using most space.

Comment: install iotop and run in terminal 'iotop -o'  to see what is writing data.  'q' to stop

Comment: Have you encrypted your home directory? Have you checked hidden folders like `~/.cache`?

Comment: Do you have ubuntuone installed? dropbox? Where did you remove the 28gb from? What folders did you remove?

Comment: @RiccardoMurri Please see the output of the command here: http://pastebin.com/VDDpuZzf

Comment: @Lekensteyn I've not got an encrypted home directory, no.  I've cleared a few items from .cache such as Spotify and Chromium (both were exceeding 600mb) but that free'd space vanished within seconds again.

Comment: @blackn1ght As @duffydack suggests above, you should me able to see what process is doing most of the writes to `.xsession-errors` using `iotop`.  My guess it's the Spotify client :-)

Comment: @RiccardoMurri Running it now.  Yup, spotify is constantly writing at 6.53mb/s.  I guess that's where my space is going then...

Comment: This is a bug report to be filed against Spotify, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `iotop -o` shows spotify writing at a constant 6.53mb/s.  Something is causing spotify to raise the errors and write to the .xsession-errors log file.

Error has been reported to spotify here:
http://getsatisfaction.com/spotify/topics/spotify_is_writing_an_obscene_amount_of_information_to_error_file